# Another How to start Python file at Windows Startup but

Tags: python

I fount a lot of **How to start Python at Windows Startup** but maybe I have something different here...

I made a Task Schedulation at Windows Startup (I want it before User loggin in) with a .vbs
The VBS run correctly, but the .py file doesn't run.
The VBS log to FILE.log correctly, but the Python script doesn't log anything (now I removed log).
It isn't called...

I tried to modify the VBS to have full path to python and to my script, but notting changed... the python script look like is not executed.

Why?

**VBS file:**

```
MyLog = "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\FILE.log"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if fso.FileExists(MyLog) = false then
   Set MyOutputLog = FSO.CreateTextFile(MyLog)
else
   Set MyOutputLog = FSO.OpenTextFile(MyLog, 8, True)
end if 

MyOutputLog.writeline Cstr(now()) & " - VBS is ok"

MyOutputLog.close()

Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run "python.exe ./myScript.py"
```

**alternative bat file:**

```
cd C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbxxxxxx8p0\python.exe "C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/myscript.py"
```

**Python file:**

```
import socket
import time
import json 
import requests

TOKEN = "<my-bot-token>"
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN)
CHAT = 111111111 # my chat ID
TEXT = "my message"


def get_IPpubl():
    endpoint = 'https://ipinfo.io/json'
    response = requests.get(endpoint, verify = True)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
        exit()

    data = response.json()

    return(data['ip'])

#check if DDNS is updated
def check_ddns():
    IPddns = socket.gethostbyname('my.dynamic.dns')
    IPpubl = get_IPpubl()
    if IPddns == IPpubl:
        return True
    return False

#check if I'm online
def test_connection():
    try:
        socket.create_connection(('google.com', 80))
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False

#functions for Telegram Bot
def get_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content.decode("utf8")
    return content

def get_json_from_url(url):
    content = get_url(url)
    js = json.loads(content)
    return js

def get_updates():
    url = URL + "getUpdates"
    js = get_json_from_url(url)
    return js

def get_last_chat_id_and_text(updates):
    num_updates = len(updates["result"])
    last_update = num_updates - 1
    text = updates["result"][last_update]["message"]["text"]
    chat_id = updates["result"][last_update]["message"]["chat"]["id"]
    return (text, chat_id)

def send_message(text, chat_id):
    url = URL + "sendMessage?text={}&chat_id={}&parse_mode={}".format(text, chat_id, 'html')
    get_url(url)

#try connection 300 times, after check DDNS and send message to Telegram
for _ in range(300):
    if(test_connection()):
        if(check_ddns()):
            TEXT = TEXT + "DDNS OK"
        else:
            TEXT = TEXT + "DDNS need an update"
        send_message(TEXT, CHAT)
        break
    time.sleep(5)
```

Task scheduler is enabled, because the VBS run...
However what I list what I select:

[General]

- Account: myuser
- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Run with highest
  privileges

[Triggers]

- At Windows Startup

[Actions]

- Start a program: myVBS.vbs (try also with /c start "C:\path_of_vbs_and_py"

Comment: obviously if I start the vbs manually everything works perfectly!

Comment: The VBS looks for the Python script in the current directory. I'm guessing it runs in a different directory from the task scheduler. Put an absolute file name instead.

Comment: already try... all combination of:
> with vbs/bat
> with complete Path for python script
> with complete Path for python.exe
=>
vbs run, python no...